# 'bad address' error from copy_to_user

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am attempting to copy a custom struct from kernel space to user space. inside user space errno returns 'bad address'.  What is the usual cause of a bad address error?

```
if(copy_to_user(info, &kernel_info, sizeof(struct prinfo)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Bad Address error means that the address location that you have given is invalid. With the case you have above I would guess it is because you are passing a copy of `info` instead of a pointer to `info`'s memory location.

Looking at the docs, `copy_to_user` is defined as

```
copy_to_user(void __user * to, const void * from, unsigned long n);
```

So unless your `info` variable is a pointer I would update your code to be:

```
if(copy_to_user(&info, &kernel_info, sizeof(struct prinfo)) ) {
    //some stuff here i guess
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that info is a pointer type and that info is pointing to a valid location it is still possible that info is pointing to an address that is not in user space which is required by the function.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem while writing a small char driver. All I was doing wrong was the function copy_to_user returns non-zero on failure, so you have to do this..

```
if(copy_to_user(void *userbuf, void *kernelbuf, long len))
    return -EFAULT;

// Continue with code..
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked about